# How to set Integer Array in Java Annotation

Tags: java, interface, java-8, annotations

I want to have an Integer Array as input in annotation interface, something like this.

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface CheckAccess {

    AccessType accessType() default AccessType.ALL;
    Integer[] permissions();

}
```

so that while providing the input, I can use some constant having integer values. Like this:-

```
@CheckAccess(permissions={CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE})

CAN_READ = 1;
CAN_WRITE=2;
```

How can I achieve this? Because when I set Integer[] it throws compilation error but works fine for String[].

Comment: Which compilation error?

Comment: `Error:(15, 12) java: invalid type for element {0} of annotation type`

Comment: You should use an enum.

Comment: Is there no way it could accept Integer[]? I mean it is a proper class not a primitive.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Not necessary.

Comment: @DaveRanjan Can it be that `CAN_READ` and `CAN_WRITE` are `int`s, not `Integer`s? Then you get a wrong type, sure. And if you use `Integer`, you can't use constants like `public static final Integer CAN_READ = 1;` because that will not be "constant expression" according to [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Comment: @DaveRanjan I think switching to `int[]` is the simplest solution.

Comment: Integer is not a primitive class, instead of using numeric value 1 2 3, you can try using  Integer.valueOf(1), or using Enum instead. @Dave Ranjan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java compiler (at least the one in my Eclipse) gives the following error message:

> Invalid type `Integer[]` for the annotation attribute `permissions`;
>   only primitive type, `String`, `Class`, annotation, enumeration are permitted
>   or one-dimensional arrays thereof

Therefore you need to replace `Integer[]` by `int[]`, like this:

```
int[] permissions() default 0;
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem, but question is `Integer`  is also a Class so it should be allowed right? I mean if String[] is what makes Integer[] so different?

Comment: You misunderstood what is meant by `Class` here. It is an annotation attribute of type `Class`, lwith value like for example `String.class` or `Object.class`.